# How do I get to the next line in the R command prompt without executing?

Tags: r

The question is so simple I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Why would you need it? Just continue typing and R will automatically prompt you with "+" as long as you reach a new line and continue listening for your input.

Comment: It's useful if you are working on a multi-line function at the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use'SHIFT-ENTER' to get to a new line in R without executing the command.

Comment: On a Mac in the GUI console, it's ctrl-shift-enter. Shift-enter, enter and return all have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Note for mac users: On mac is Ctrl + Enter

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(1,2,3.5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
+ 16,17,18,19,20)
```

I did not write the “+” at the outset of the second line. If you hit the return key after the last comma on the first line, the plus sign will be produced by R as a new prompt and you can go on typing in the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a mac user, try "Option + Enter", which works for me in R 4.1.2 (High Sierra).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30280828)